# Gstreamer 1.13.91 + Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, gstreamer

I'm trying to setup node.js server with Gstream v1.13.91 but when I'm start javascript file I get the following error:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\testicek\camera>node main.js
LiveCam parameters: { broadcast_addr: '127.0.0.1',
  broadcast_port: 12000,
  ui_addr: '127.0.0.1',
  ui_port: 11000,
  gst_tcp_addr: '127.0.0.1',
  gst_tcp_port: 10000 }
GstLaunch found: C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0.exe
GStreamer version: 1.13.91
GStreamer pipeline: ksvideosrc ! decodebin ! jpegenc ! multipartmux  boundary="-
-videoboundary" ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=10000

(gst-launch-1.0:7296): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer
\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdecklink.dll': 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\
gstreamer-1.0\libgstdecklink.dll': Selected module unable to find.

(gst-launch-1.0:7296): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer
\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenh264.dll': 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\
gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenh264.dll': Selected module unable to find.

(gst-launch-1.0:7296): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer
\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstpango.dll': 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\gst
reamer-1.0\libgstpango.dll': Selected module unable to find.

(gst-launch-1.0:7296): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer
\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrsvg.dll': 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstr
eamer-1.0\libgstrsvg.dll': Selected module unable to find.

(gst-launch-1.0:7296): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer
\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsoundtouch.dll': 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\li
b\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsoundtouch.dll': Selected module unable to find.

(gst-launch-1.0:7296): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\gstreamer
\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttaglib.dll': 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\gs
treamer-1.0\libgsttaglib.dll': Selected module unable to find?.
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "ksvideosrc"
```

What should I do to resolve this problem? 
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Maybe you need to add `C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin` to your `PATH` variable so that required `.dll` files can be found.